# Table with user activities - design issue

Tags: sql, database, database-design

On my site user can make some items and those items goes in `Items` table.
Users can also follow each other and those data I store in `Followings` table.
Now I need one table that keep track of user activities, so I have created:

```
Users{UserId, Username, FirstName, LastName}
Items{ItemId, Title, CreatedByUserId}
Activity{ActivityId, ActivityTypeId, UserId, ItemId}
```

Here `ItemId` can be or `ItemId` from `Items` table or `UserId` from `Users` table.
Is this design good or there is better approach to do this?

**Edit:** I have added table structures. The point is that I wan't to add record to that Activity table every time when user create item or start to follow some user. So I can always track what user did on the site.

Comment: For a good answer, it would be better to see the structure of each table that you refer in the question.

Comment: I have added table structures. The point is that I wan't to add record to that Activity table every time when user create item or start to follow some user. So I can always track what user did on the site. That is the goal of Activity table. I have a type in it. But is it good to use one column FK for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here ItemId can be or ItemId from Items table or UserId from Users table.

This will prevent the DBMS from enforcing the foreign key. If you go down that route, better separate these fields (so you can make foreign keys towards their respective tables) and use a CHECK to ensure exactly one of them is non-NULL:

[image]

```
CHECK (
    (ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL AND FOLLOWED_USER_ID IS NULL)
    OR (ITEM_ID IS NULL AND FOLLOWED_USER_ID IS NOT NULL)
)
```

The `ACTIVITY` PK is crafted so it is easy to query for a "timeline" of a specific user and is friendly to [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).

*(You may or may not need `ACTIVITY.TYPE` depending on what exactly you want to track.)*

---

The alternative would be to have a separate table for each kind of activity:

[image]

*(And you could add a `TYPE` field in `FOLLOW_ACTIVITY` to distinguish between "follow" and "unfollow".)*

---

Another alternative would be to [inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11462181/533120) users and items from a common parent "class" and then link to that class:

[image]

This design is probably an overkill in this case, but could be useful if you later add many other kinds of objects that could be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Items{ItemID,descr,UserIDCreator,date-time}
User{UserID,descr}
Followings{UserIDFollowed,UserIDFollower,date-time}
```

now if you wont all items created by eser use user code on items
the same on followings I add date-time for chrono select

You can create atriggered table or a view this depends on cardinality of data

If the same object can be share between users

```
Items{ItemID,descr,}
UserItems{UserID,descr,ItemId,date-time}
User{UserID,descr}
Followings{UserIDFollowed,UserIDFollower,date-time}
```

I hope to be useful